# How to proceed with the given example?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-6

In order to get a nice intro to asp.net mvc i started working on w3schools example. this example is super easy to understand and follow. I did exactly as shown in the below tutorials.
[http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_intro.asp][1]

All steps prior to controller addition work fine
But when i try adding a controller i get the below error:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

### Unable to retrieve metadata for 'MvcApplication1.Models.MovieDB'. Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'.

I have looked for the similar error online and came across solutions that were created by using lower versions of entity framework. In my project i have installed entity framework 6 using nuget packages.

Guide me where I am wrong. I don't have any previous entity framework knowledge nor do I understand which suits which version of mvc.

As the example guides I created a asp.net mvc 3 web application using razor and html 5.

Please guide me where I am wrong or how to solve this?

Comment: following the below path on my pc for adding entity framework references:   Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication1\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib   ... i get 2 folders ...one for net 4 and the other for net 4.5... if i add 4 , i dont get any error prior to controller addition ..but in case of 4.5 i go get error that dbcontext and dbset present in model file are not identifiable.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext` doesn't exist anymore in EF6, but I don't get why you would want to work with MVC3 for a new application, while MVC5 is already out for more than a year. If you really want to continue with this, just uninstall entity framework through NuGet and install EF5.